# Get Sortable Jquery-ui data from list after sorting

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, jquery-ui

I'm having a problem with getting the sorted data form `id="#playlist_save"`.

`id ="#playlist_save"` starts with an empty `<ol></ol>` list.

Then the user can sort the items they need form  :

```
<ol class="simple_with_animation vertical">
    $videos
</ol>
```

To the list:

```
<div class="group">
    <ol id="playlist_save" class="simple_with_animation vertical">
    </ol>
</div>
```

But when I want to save the data after it has been sorted, I get no data from

```
console.log(postdata);
```

Please help me out! :(

For a better understanding visit: http://music-hot40.com/Playlist.php

PHP

```
 $ii = 1;
foreach ($searchResponse['items'] as $searchResult) {
    switch ($searchResult['id']['kind']) {
        case 'youtube#video':
            $videos .= sprintf('<li id="listItem_%u"><img alt="youtube_image" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/%s/hqdefault.jpg" style="height: 120px; width: 120px;"></img><font color="#953e31">%s</font> %s</li>', $ii, $searchResult['id']['videoId'], $searchResult['snippet']['title'], $searchResult['id']['videoId']);
            $ii++;
            break;
    }
}
$htmlBody .= <<<END
<div class="group">
    <ol class="simple_with_animation vertical">
        $videos
    </ol>
</div>
```

END;

NEXT GROUP

```
<div class="group">
    <ol id="playlist_save" class="simple_with_animation vertical">
    </ol>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var adjustment;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("ol.simple_with_animation").sortable({
        group: 'group',
        pullPlaceholder: false,
        // animation on drop
        onDrop: function ($item, container, _super) {
            var $clonedItem = $('<li/>').css({height: 0});
            $item.before($clonedItem);
            $clonedItem.animate({'height': $item.height()});

            $item.animate($clonedItem.position(), function () {
                $clonedItem.detach();
                _super($item, container);
            });
        },
        // set $item relative to cursor position
        onDragStart: function ($item, container, _super) {
            var offset = $item.offset(),
                    pointer = container.rootGroup.pointer;

            adjustment = {
                left: pointer.left - offset.left,
                top: pointer.top - offset.top
            };

            _super($item, container);
        },
        onDrag: function ($item, position) {
            $item.css({
                left: position.left - adjustment.left,
                top: position.top - adjustment.top
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Save data from `#playlist_save` to database (not yet) AND Log data in console.log

```
 $(function () {
            // log data
            $("#playlist_save").sortable({
                update: function (event, ui) {
                    var postdata = $(this).sortable('serialize');
                    console.log(postdata);
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two `jquery` plugins with the name `sortable`, and the one that's defined the latest doesn't have `update`. This file:

```
<script src="js/jquery-sortable.js"></script>
```

calls a `sortable` plugin that has many function, but not update. When you run $(...).sortable(), you're calling this plugin, so update won't be triggered as it is in the standard `jquery-ui sortable`.

If you want to keep features of this `custom sortable` on one list, but use `update` on another, you should have two different names for your plugins so there's no confusion. Like this for example:

In this file js/jquery-sortable.js change last line to:

```
}(jQuery, window, 'customSortable');
```

Then in you javascript, call it like this:

```
$("ol.simple_with_animation").customSortable({
```